# have an issue with a function

Tags: mysql, sql, function

So i'm trying to create a function for a school project, the idea behind the function is pull all ingredients from a recipe database. When I use the function I created the MySQL error states 1415 not allowed to return a result set from a function. Here is my code.

```
DELIMITER ??
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS fxn_get_ingredients??
CREATE FUNCTION fxn_get_ingredients (ingredientList VARCHAR (100))
RETURNS VARCHAR (100) DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
SELECT
i.ingredientName AS 'Ingredient Name'
FROM ingredients i
INNER JOIN recipe_ingredients ri ON i.ingredientID=ri.ingredientID
INNER JOIN recipes r ON ri.recipeID=r.recipeID
WHERE r.recipeTitle = ingredientlist;
END ??
DELIMITER ;
```

I'm not sure what this error means or how to resolve the issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did any of the answers help you? Please consider accepting an answer, if your question is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Table valued function` are not present in `MySQL`; so you can't return a table from a function and instead choose use a perocedure. An alternative would be like below

```
DELIMITER ??
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS fxn_get_ingredients??
CREATE FUNCTION fxn_get_ingredients (ingredientList VARCHAR (100))
RETURNS tinyint(1)
BEGIN

 DECLARE result INT DEFAULT 0; 

 CREATE TABLE temp_table(ingredientName varchar(100));

INSERT INTO temp_table
SELECT
i.ingredientName AS 'Ingredient Name'
FROM ingredients i
INNER JOIN recipe_ingredients ri ON i.ingredientID=ri.ingredientID
INNER JOIN recipes r ON ri.recipeID=r.recipeID
WHERE r.recipeTitle = ingredientlist;

 SET result = 1;

 RETURN result ;

END ??
DELIMITER ;
```

Than call the function and then can do a `select * from temp_table;`

Comment: Hmm, looks like he already tried some but actually didn't tried referring the document. Instead of saying you can do this this ... thought better would be giving a example. Now he can enhance on it.

Comment: thanks, not really looking at the answer, I do want to figure this out myself, unfortunatley my instructor kind of breezed by this part and now I feel like I have to reteach myself it.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to [create a `procedure` instead of a `function`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-procedure.html). Functions can't return multiple rows.

If you need to use a function, you may look into the mysql specific SQL extension [GROUP_CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat). If you formulate your SQL query so that the results are in one group you can use this function to add strings of each result row together.

Comment: that is what I was thinking, but this is what my instructor was asking... Create a stored function called fxn_get_ingredients that returns a list of ingredients given a recipe title. Invoke the stored procedure as follows:

Comment: See my comment about GROUP_CONCAT.